# Android Swipe View that doesn't use the whole Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-4.1-jelly-bean

Is it possible to use the ViewPager/Swipe View to create swiping fragments within a section of an activity, rather than taking up the whole activity?

Currently, when I swipe on the activity the whole page changes to the new fragment, instead, I want the fragment that changes to take up a small section on the activity layout.

Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_skip);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }
}
```

ViewPager Class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: *Any ideas on how to achieve my goal?* - don't set the ViewPager to fill the entire activity like you currently do.Place it only where you need it.

Comment: Well I tried to set it to 'wrap_content' but that still fills the activity because the ViewPager seems to take up the maximum space provided.

Comment: That's something that a ViewPager does, you also didn't show anything about what's its content. Did you try giving it a specific height(like 100 dp for example). If you're thinking about a specific layout you should post an image or at least try to explain it in words.

Comment: The content of the fragment is a few widgets (an image and some text) inside a RelativeLayout with the height set to wrap_content. When I set the height of the ViewPager to 250dp (for example) it did maintain that value, but I didn't want to use a specific value because then there is less fluent support for varying screen sizes.